# Itertools saturation after 1 billion permutation

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wrote the following code to calculate the mean of the sums obtained between all the permutations of a list of lists:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

r = 13
c = 5
a = np.arange(r*c).reshape(r, c)
a = list(itertools.product(*a))

res = sum([sum(e) for e in a])/len(a)
```

The code crashes as r seems slightly too big and itertools/python can not handle it. Is there any other ways to calculate **res** without having the code crashing?

Comment: When reporting that _"code crashes"_, please provide the exact stack trace and exception message.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a coding challenge, which in the end does not require any iteration at all. It should be possible to calculate the result directly from `r` and `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are needlessly collecting first the `products`, and then the individual `sums` in `lists` when you can just as well just iterate the iterators. You also don't need `len` of the list, since you can compute the number of products directly.

```
res = sum(sum(e) for e in itertools.product(*a))/c**r
```

This will consume much less memory, which might keep you computer from freezing or crashing. However, for `r=13` and `c=5`, this still means testing `c**r = 1,220,703,125` combinations, which is probably too much for Python.

However, since you are getting *all* products, each element will appear in all products the same number of times, so you do not have to actually calculate and iterate the products at all. Instead, you can calculate the average sum of the products directly like this:

```
res = sum(sum(a)) // c   # here, a is the numpy array, not the product iterator
```

(This is for all lists having the same number of elements; if the lists have different sizes, the formula will be a bit more complicated, but can still be calculated directly without any loops.)